# VB.Net snippets - get function or sub name

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

It would be very helpful if visual studio 2015/VB.net snippets are capable of getting the function name they're written in.
For example a function like so:

```
private function SomeFunctionA() as Boolean
<insert snippet here and it generates 'SomeText - SomeFunctionA>
end function

private sub aSubRoutine() 
<insert snippet here and it generates 'SomeText - aSubRoutine>
end sub
```

If it's possible or not, any information would be very helpful (this is a tricky one to google!) thanks in advance.

PS - I'm aware of how to create snippets, but I don't know any syntax that can do the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using reflection.

Add this to the top of your file:

```
Imports System.Reflection.MethodBase
```

Then you can use the following Functions:

```
GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType().Name 'Gets the name of the Class/Module

GetCurrentMethod().Name 'Gets the current Sub or Function name
```

So the following is what you need:

```
Private Sub aSubRoutine()
    MessageBox.Show(GetCurrentMethod().Name) 'Shows aSubRoutine
End Sub
```